# How do I know whether the image is rotated or inverted while extracting from pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Task: My task is to extract all images from pdf and save it to a local file.

Problem:  When I am trying to extract images from pdf, I have seen that all images are not loading in properly.
Consider my pdf as 3 images. When I am trying to extract images I have seen that few images are saving in rotated, inverted or with some other rotation angles.
I am not sure what properties does that image consists of in pdf.

Question: 
 1. I want to know whether an image is rotated or not?
 2. If Yes, then I want to know in which angle is that rotated. So that I can change that rotation and save it to my local.

Is there any method or property by which we can know the above properties?

Below is the code I have used:

```
@Override
protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
    String operation = operator.getName();
    if ("Do".equals(operation)) {
        COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get(0);
        PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);
        if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) xobject;
            int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
            int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
            System.out.println(image.getMetadata());//output null
            // same image to local
            BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            bImage = image.getImage();
        System.out.println(bImage.getPropertyNames());//output null
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "PNG", new File("C:/PdfBox_Examples/" + "image_" + imageNumber + ".png"));
            System.out.println("Image saved.");
            imageNumber++;

        } else if (xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
            PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject) xobject;
            showForm(form);
        }
    } else {
        super.processOperator(operator, operands);
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially you need to consider the value of the current transformation matrix at the time that **Do** is processed, and the value of the page rotation attribute.

Comment: getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();

Comment: Thanks,
Now I am able get matrix with below code
Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
    float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
    float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();

Can I consider image is rotated in yaxis if ImageYScale is negative
and rotated in x axis if  imageXScale is negative?

Comment: It's more complex, the shear must also be considered. Here's code to get the rotation: `Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())))` with `m` being a `Matrix`. Detecting flips is another story.

Comment: Thanks, Tilman Hausherr,
Information was very helpful to solve my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that, consider answering the question yourself to show what code you used.

Comment: After going through all comments I have understood the exact problem I have.
My actual problem was about flips. Unknowingly I thought it is because of rotations.
But below link helped me in understanding why images will be extracted in flipped manner in some pdfs

https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractImages.java#L140